# Java Enum to String Map maintaining consistency

Tags: java, enums

I am new to Java and working on writing a Enum to String Map for headers.

```
public class Header {

    // When adding HeaderType make sure it is consistent with the header name map
    public enum HeaderType {
        MARKER,
        WIDTH,
        ......
    };

    private String name;
    private String value;
    private HeaderType headerType;

    // Create an immutable map for header enum to header names
    private static final Map<HeaderType, String> headerNameMap;
    static {
        Map<HeaderType, String> headerNameMapTemp = new HashMap<HeaderType, String>();
        headerNameMapTemp.put(HeaderType.MARKER, "MA");
        headerNameMapTemp.put(HeaderType.WIDTH, "WI");
        headerNameMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(headerNameMapTemp);
    }

    public Header(HeaderType headerType, String value) {
        this.headerType = headerType;
        this.name = Header.getHeaderName(this.headerType);
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static String getHeaderName(HeaderType headerType) {
        return headerName.get(headerType);
    }
```

In the above code I use HeaderType enum and use an immutable HashMap to convert from enum to header name. As you can see adding another header type involves adding it in the map as well. So the user of this should make sure it's added in two places to avoid any mess later. Are their any clean alternatives for this functionality?

Answer (score 6):

You can make the header name a field in the `enum` itself, like this:

```
public enum HeaderType {
    MARKER("MA"),
    WIDTH("WI");
    // FOO(), BAR; Won't compile

    private final String name;

    private HeaderType(String name) {
        this.name = name;   
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This way it will not be possible to add a new `HeaderType` without specifying a corresponding name as well and your `getHeaderName` method could simply be replaced with a call to `getName()`.

You can enumerate all type/name combinations using the `enum`'s `values()` method:

```
for (HeaderType headerType : HeaderType.values()) {
    System.out.println(headerType.getName());
}
```

Running sample: https://ideone.com/B5LwQz